# function st_length3d(geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgis

Whenever I execute this query:

SELECT ST_Length3D(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(0 0 0,5 0 3,5 10 5)')); in postgresql it is throwing an error like ERROR: function st_length3d(geometry) does not exist SQL state: 42883

but this query running fine and showing result SELECT ST_Length(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(0 0 0,5 0 3,5 10 5)'));

It seems that ST_Length3D is not added in my system defined function any idea how to recover this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`ST_3DLength`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_3DLength.html).

The function was renamed from `ST_Length3D` to `ST_3DLength` in PostGIS 2.0.